# Python implementation of Netcat, new design

Tags: python, python-2.x, networking, osx

I've made a simple netcat in Python and would appreciate any advice/opinions of how I've implemented it.

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

import netcat


def main(*args):
    netcat.connect('localhost', 4444)
    netcat.listen('', 4444)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(*sys.argv))
```

netcat.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import select
import socket
from contextlib import closing

from servers import Server
from cat import cat_line


def netcat(sock, infile=sys.stdin, outfile=sys.stdout):
    with closing(sock) as s:
        sf = s.makefile()
        while True:
            r, w, e = select.select([s, infile], [], [])
            if s in r:
                if not cat_line(sf, outfile):
                    break
            if infile in r:
                if not cat_line(infile, sf):
                    break


def listen(lhost, lport, *args, **kwargs):
    with Server(lhost, lport) as server:
        client = server.get_client()
        netcat(client, *args, **kwargs)


def connect(rhost, rport, *args, **kwargs):
    server = socket.create_connection((rhost, rport))
    with closing(server) as s:
        netcat(s, *args, **kwargs)
```

servers.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket


class Server(object):

    def __init__(self, lhost, lport):
        self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self._sock.bind((lhost, lport))
        self._sock.listen(1)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self.get_client()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        self.close()

    def get_client(self):
        return self._sock.accept()[0]

    def close(self):
        self._sock.close()
```

cat.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys


def cat_line(infile=sys.stdin, outfile=sys.stdout):
    line = infile.readline()
    if not line:
        return False
    outfile.write(line)
    outfile.flush()
    return True


def cat(infile=sys.stdin, outfile=sys.stdout):
    while True:
        if not cat_line(infile, outfile):
            break
```

**Edit:** Maybe I should take the responsibility of closing the socket from the netcat function...

```
def netcat(sock, infile=sys.stdin, outfile=sys.stdout):
    sf = sock.makefile()
    while True:
        r, w, e = select.select([sock, infile], [], [])
        if sock in r and not cat_line(sf, outfile):
                break
        if infile in r and not cat_line(infile, sf):
                break
```

and instead, put that functionality into the listen function?

```
def listen(lhost, lport, *args, **kwargs):
    with Server(lhost, lport) as server:
        client = server.get_client()
    with closing(client) as c:
        netcat(c, *args, **kwargs)
```

Also...

```
def cat(infile=sys.stdin, outfile=sys.stdout):
    while True:
        if not cat_line(infile, outfile):
            break
```

could be

```
def cat(infile=sys.stdin, outfile=sys.stdout):
    while cat_line(infile, outfile):
        pass
```

[github](https://github.com/reclusivecoder/netsnake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## test.py

If you look at the definition of `main()`, you will see that it doesn't explicitly return anything.  By default, functions return `None`, so you will always be exiting with `None`.  Since it is always the same, it is useless even to use `sys.exit()`.  The program will exit once the file has been read, so you don't need to tell Python to do that.  If you want to use exit codes, you'll need `main()` to return them.

`main()` doesn't use its arguments, so why give it any?  If `sys.argv` is ignored, take it out and remove the useless import of `sys`.

## netcat.py

> ```
> if s in r:
>     if not cat_line(sf, outfile):
>         break
> ```

The only time your program does something in the case of `s in r` is when `not cat_line(sf, outfile)`.  Since you want to handle only the cases where both are true, use `and`:

```
if s in r and not cat_line(sf, outfile):
    break
```

Same with the next `if` block.  I wouldn't recommend it because it makes your lines too long, but you *could* put both `if` blocks in one:

```
if ((s in r) and not cat_line(sf, outfile)) or ((infile in r) and not cat_line(infile, sf):
    break
```

`servers.py` and `cat.py` look okay to me, but *my* opinion is that you don't need multiple files.  You don't have a bunch of lines that need to be split up, so you might as well put all of it in one file (not including `test.py`).

Comment: Thank you for you feedback, I don't know why I did that with main, I don't usually do it but I think I'd seen it in someone's code recently. I'm going to change those if statements and put all files into one. Thanks :)